# Writing function in Python saves only the last string (Python)

Tags: python, string, save, pos-tagger

I am doing pos tagging using 'nltk' in Python and the code below works perfectly fine when I print it.

```
import nltk 
import pos_tag
import nltk.tokenize 
import numpy

f = open(r'C:\Users\sample_data.txt')
data = f.readlines()

#Parse the text file for NER with POS Tagging
for line in data:
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(line)
    tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
    #print (tagged)

output = open(r"C:\Users\output3.csv", "w")
output.write(str(tagged))
f.close()
```

So when I print the code above, the output looks like this, which is exactly what I want.

```
[('This', 'DT'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('a', 'DT'), ('simple', 'JJ'), ('sentence', 'NN')]
[('I', 'PRP'), ('love', 'VBP'), ('this', 'DT'), ('company', 'NN'), ('.', '.'), ('This', 'DT'), ('company', 'NN'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('so', 'RB'), ('good', 'JJ'), ('.', '.')]
[('I', 'PRP'), ('am', 'VBP'), ('not', 'RB'), ('inovlved', 'VBN'), ('with', 'IN'), ('this', 'DT'), ('work', 'NN'), ('.', '.'), ('So', 'RB'), ('hard', 'JJ'), ('!', '.')]
[('What', 'WP'), ('are', 'VBP'), ('you', 'PRP'), ('doing', 'VBG'), ('?', '.'), ('Are', 'NNP'), ('you', 'PRP'), ('nut', 'RB'), ('?', '.')]
[('Can', 'MD'), ('I', 'PRP'), ('borrow', 'VB'), ('your', 'PRP$'), ('jar', 'NN'), ('?', '.'), ('Just', 'NNP'), ('for', 'IN'), ('today', 'NN'), ('.', '.')]
```

But when I write it using the last three lines in the code, it saves only the last string in the text file (i.e.,[('Can', 'MD'), ('I', 'PRP'), ('borrow', 'VB'), ('your', 'PRP$'), ('jar', 'NN'), ('?', '.'), ('Just', 'NNP'), ('for', 'IN'), ('today', 'NN'), ('.', '.')]).

I would like to save the entire results in txt or csv file, and one string in each [ ] should be saved in one line in txt or csv file.

I am really really new to Python, so help will be appreciated.

Comment: `tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)` redefines tag for each line in data. By the end, you're only saving the last line.

Answer (score 2):

You should save each line in a list and then write the whole list:

```
tagged_list = []
#Parse the text file for NER with POS Tagging
for line in data:
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(line)
    tagged_list.append(str(nltk.pos_tag(tokens)))

output = open(r"C:\Users\output3.csv", "w")
output.write('\n'.join(tagged_list))
output.close()
```

In `tagged_list` you add all the lines to write. With `'\n'.join(tagged)` you write them, separated by '\n' (i.e. each in a different line)

Comment: thank you so much! It works perfectly. Just one minor error is writing tagged_list instead of tagged inside of the parenthesis right after join. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You have an indentation error.

```
import nltk 
import pos_tag
import nltk.tokenize 
import numpy

f = open(r'C:\Users\sample_data.txt')
data = f.readlines()

#Parse the text file for NER with POS Tagging
for line in data:
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(line)
    tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
    #print (tagged)

    output = open(r"C:\Users\output3.csv", "a")
    output.write(str(tagged)+'\n')
f.close()
output.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: To answer you original question, in your original code you need to call `output.write(str(tagged))` in the loop.

Even if other answers do answer the question, I would like to suggest some changes to your implementation

- try using `with` when handling resources whenever you can as it closes the resources automatically in the end
- you can simply iterate the `f` variable once the file is open

The end result would look like this:

```
import nltk

# file will be closed once out of the scope
with open(r'C:\Users\sample_data.txt') as f:  
    with open(r'C:\Users\output3.csv', 'w') as output:
        for line in f:
            tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(line)
            tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
            output.write(str(tagged)+'\n')
```